# OR all elements of a std_logic_vector with a flexible size

Tags: vector, vhdl

I have a vector that has a configurable size like

```
signal a_vector : std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
```

where `size` is defined in a configuration file. What I now would like to do is to OR all elements of `a_vector` into a separate `std_logic` in a way like

```
signal result : std_logic;
result <= a_vector(0) or a_vector(1) or ... or a_vector(size-1)
```

Is there a way to do this with a `GENERATE` statement, I couldn't figure that out.

scary_jeff's answer works like a charm for the given problem. Is there a similar way if I'd have

```
type byte_array is array (0 to size) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal a_vector : byte_array;
```

and I'd like to have

```
result <= a_vector(0)(1) or a_vector(1)(1) or ... or a_vector(size-1)(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using VHDL2008 or later, which has 'reductive' `and` and `or` functions built in, you can simply write `result <= or(a_vector);` or `result <= or a_vector;`.

If not, you can use a `for` loop (not a `generate` loop). You could put this loop in a function if you wanted.

```
function reductive_or (a_vector : std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
  variable r : std_logic := '0';
begin
  for i in a_vector`range loop
    r := r or a_vector(i);
  end loop;
  return r;
end function;
```

Comment: Is it also possible for specific elements of vectors of a vector array (see edit)?

Comment: if you dont mind using "non-standard" code and you're stuck with VHDL 1993, all tools Ive ever use include std_logic_misc in the ieee library, which has an `or_reduce` function.

Comment: Your -2008 right hand expression doesn't need parentheses.